# Recognise columns in different SQL statements

Tags: sql

I am curious if it is possible to recognise if, given 2 arbitrary SQL queries, if a column was renamed?

**For example:**

```sql
SELECT A as foo FROM Table1;
```

gets updated to:

```sql
SELECT A as bar FROM Table1;
```

It is easy to recognise that column `foo` got renamed to `bar` but is it possible in general?

Comment: by renamed you mean using some or a different alias?

Comment: Yes, but also the case of removing an alias is valid, so the column gets its original name.

Comment: The layer which receives the result set generally doesn't "know" what the original name of the column is.  They would only see the alias.  Maybe you can elaborate on why you think you have this problem.

Comment: I am not in this layer. I do not have the results. I only have two SQL queries and want to detect if a column got 'renamed'.

Comment: Sure! In what context? SQL has no real concept of reflection, but you could do some string processing in any suitable language and build a 'common table-columns' list :)

Comment: So, basically, you want to be able to tell (as the consumer of a result set? Or by statically analyzing the query?) which column from which base table is mapped to each column in the result set? I'll assume we ignore expressions, including nop-expressions (such as `A + '' as foo` if `A` is a string column).

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice too much work.

Comment: The JDBC API has function calls to detect that. But only very few JDBC drivers actually support it (most return the column alias for both calls)